# Hiding entire website to visitors on Kentico?

Tags: kentico

Is it possible to hide an entire website behind a log-in screen? Making the visitor login to see the content. I know there are plugins like this on Wordpress but I am unable to find something for Kentico.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  At the root of the website (master page) select it.  Then go to Properties>Security and in the Access section of that page, select yes for the "Requires authentication" attribute and save the page.  This will force the user to the login page you have defined in your web.config OR in your Settings to authenticate first.  This will be inherited by default through the rest of the child pages.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why it wouldn't do anything if I do that and it still goes to the website (I don't see anything different happening).

Comment: Nevermind, I had to go into Settings and set "Check page permissions:" to "All Pages". THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: Yes, in the Settings you need to ensure that is checked.  You can also check that box on webparts as well if you're rendering a dynamic menu available for only some roles and not other roles.